# Create list by cell color

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-data-validation

I have a master list of trading cards. I'd love to be able to use a color coding system. For example, if Green is cards I've already collected, when I highlight the background of the cell green, I want it to create a list on a separate page using the contents of those highlighted cells. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome. On this site tags question title should not include tags (we have a tag system for tagging question, by the way tags have tag excerpts and wikis with use guidelines). Regarding the content of your question please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

- perhaps try like this using conditional formatting and data validation:

  [image]